# why when i pass a parameter in str this will be byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

i have a function that receive a str value but when i execute the error say that is a byte value:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sdand\Documents\Python\Engine\engine.py", line 4, in <module>
    print (find.crawl_web('https://google.com',4))
  File "C:\Users\sdand\Documents\Python\Engine\finder.py", line 68, in crawl_web
    links = self.get_all_links(content)
  File "C:\Users\sdand\Documents\Python\Engine\finder.py", line 20, in get_all_links
    url, endpos = self.get_next_target(page)
  File "C:\Users\sdand\Documents\Python\Engine\finder.py", line 7, in get_next_target
    start_link = s.find('<a href=')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

this is the function where i call get_all_links:

```
def crawl_web(self,seed, max_depth):
        tocrawl = [seed]
        crawled = []
        next_depth = []
        depth = 0
        index=[]

        while tocrawl and depth <= max_depth:
            page = tocrawl.pop()
            if page not in crawled:
                #here content content is str
                content = self.get_page(page)
                self.add_page_to_index(index,page,content)
                links = self.get_all_links(content)
                self.union(next_depth,links)
                crawled.append(page)
            if not tocrawl:
                tocrawl, next_depth = next_depth, []
                depth = depth+1
        return index
```

this is get_page:

```
def get_page(self,url):
        try:
            import urllib.request

            return  urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
        except:
            return ""
```

this is get_all_links:

```
def get_all_links(self,page):
        #but here it is byte i dont now why
        links=[]
        while True:
            url, endpos = self.get_next_target(page)
            print(url)
            if url != None:
                links.append(url)
                page = page[endpos:]
            else:
                break
        return links
```

i don't now why my str variable "Content" is converted in byte type in get_all_links, somebody can explain this to me, and how i can resolve it?

Comment: yes but when i do print(type(page)) in get_all_links it return a byte object

Comment: When using the `.read()`, you cast to str, so maybe that could be the cause of your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may not be aware, `.read()` returns a `byte` object, not `str`, although using `byte` object is more recommended when web scraping, the easiest fix though is to cast it to `str` by decoding it.

```
return urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: i use that but it returns this error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 7799: invalid start byte

Comment: You can try doing this instead `.decode('utf-8', 'replace')`, or if you know what encoding it uses, decode to that instead. This is one of the reasons why we like to keep it as bytes.

Comment: When you're doing web scraping, the proper encoding will be specified by the http response or the meta tag. It's best to use a library that understands this and does the decoding for you so that you get a Unicode string back.